# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: too early for operation error

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, software-center, snap

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my computer and majority of the software from the Ubuntu software store gives me this error:

```
too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged.
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I'm using 3.7 GB memory, Intel Core i3-3220 CPU@3.30Ghz x 4, 64-bit, 245 HD. I have already installed all the recent updates.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain, step by step, how you get the error message so we can try to duplicate it.

Comment: Seems to be snap-related. Some Arch users have mentioned the error: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cant-install-or-refresh-snaps-on-arch-linux/8690

Comment: I tried everything in that post and I still get $ sudo snap refresh
error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not
       acknowledged

Comment: I get this error very intermittently while provisioning a Virtualbox Ubuntu 18.04 LTS guest virtual machine using Vagrant. If I just destroy the VM and provision again it works. The Vagrantfile invokes `snap` as part of the provision.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the time and time zone, otherwise an error will be reported:

```
error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not 
acknowledged
```

To adjust, run:

```
apt install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate ntp.sjtu.edu.cn    #(NTP server address of Shanghai Jiaotong University Network Center）
timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Shanghai
```

You can choose the ntp server and timezone near you.

Doing a `sudo apt purge snapd` followed by a `sudo apt install snapd` solves this issue in both cases.